# Delete Dynamic Row entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have the  following html  view and javascript :

```js
var rowCount = 1;
$(".add_more_rows").click(function() {
  rowCount++;

  var recRow = '<p id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td>\n\
<td><input name="" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td>\n\
<td><input name="" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td>\n\
<td> <span id="remove_row' + rowCount + '" class="remove_row' + rowCount + '" style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">Delete Entry</span> </td></tr> </p>';

  $('.remove_row' + rowCount + '').click(function() {

    $('#rowCount' + rowCount).remove();
  });
  $('#addedRows').append(recRow);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table rules="all" style="background:#fff;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Name</td>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Email</td>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Mobile</td>
      <td><span class="add_more_rows" id="add_more_rows" style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">
                                Add More
                            </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowId">
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" size="17%" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
  </table>
  <div id="addedRows"></div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

When I click on the  Add more button, a new row should be added to my table which works perfectly and each row is assigned a unique id and class but when I try to click on the  Delete Entry to delete the  specific row, it fails. Please advise what is it that am not doing right on the  remove_row that prevents the trigger to take place and also for the  row not to be deleted.

Comment: Try "emptying" the container. Add `$('#rowCount' + rowCount).empty();` after `$('#rowCount' + rowCount).remove();`

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you've done this `<p id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" />`
**<p>** isn't a self closing tag. Remove the `/` at the end. Maybe it would help

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a lot of unnecessary code there. You needn't set up individual ids etc. just figure out which `<tr>` is being deleted by which anchor tag is being clicked.

```
$("a.remove_row").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

The snippet shows deleting in action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=3>
  <tr>
    <td>Line 1</td>
    <td>Line 1</td>
    <td>Line 1</td>
    <td>Line 1</td>
    <td><a href=#>delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line 2</td>
    <td>Line 2</td>
    <td>Line 2</td>
    <td>Line 2</td>
    <td><a href=#>delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line 3</td>
    <td>Line 3</td>
    <td>Line 3</td>
    <td>Line 3</td>
    <td><a href=#>delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line 4</td>
    <td>Line 4</td>
    <td>Line 4</td>
    <td>Line 4</td>
    <td><a href=#>delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Side Note:**

1. You definitely shouldn't be wrapping table rows in `<p>` elements (which is why I don't like @Pugazh's answer). It's not invalid in an XML sense but it's very poor html wise. There is also no need, you can add your `rowCount` directly to you `<tr>` (but it's also unnecessary with this answer).
2. You should be using css to style `input` boxes (especially rather than putting it into your template). The fiddle below demonstrates this to a basic degree.

**Fully Functional Example:**

I have put together this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xbvs3n7/1/)** to demonstrate cleanly **adding** and **removing** rows (without some of the messiness that you have above). As @Ohohorion says, event bubbling is what you really need to exploit in order to remove rows that have been dynamically inserted. Rather than binding the event to `table` though, it's better to attach it to the `document` (as in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xbvs3n7/1/))

Answer (score 2):

Select the parent element and remove the same from DOM. I have added below function to the javascript and additoinally added `onClick="javascript:fnRemove(this);"` to the `span`

```
function fnRemove(t){
    $(t).parent('p').remove();
}
```

---

```js
var rowCount = 1;
$(".add_more_rows").click(function() {
  rowCount++;

  var recRow = '<p id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td>\n\
<td><input name="" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td>\n\
<td><input name="" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td>\n\
<td> <span id="remove_row' + rowCount + '" onClick="javascript:fnRemove(this);" class="remove_row' + rowCount + '" style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">Delete Entry</span> </td></tr> </p>';

  $('#addedRows').append(recRow);

});

function fnRemove(t) {
  $(t).parent('p').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table rules="all" style="background:#fff;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Name</td>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Email</td>
      <td style="font-size:14px;">Mobile</td>
      <td><span class="add_more_rows" id="add_more_rows" style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">
                                Add More
                            </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowId">
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" size="17%" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
  </table>
  <div id="addedRows"></div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('click','.remove_row' + rowCount,function () {

                $('#rowCount' + rowCount).remove();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Loads of unnecessary code and bad practises such as wrapping table rows with paragraph tag (`<p>`). But it is all about learning. ;)

I advise reading about [event bubbling](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/) and how it helps in situations like these where you otherwise have to initialise new listener each time.

In this case, instead of initialising a new event listener each time, you can use something like this:

```
$('table').on('click', '.remove_row', function () {
```

Instead of:

```
$('.remove_row' + rowCount + '').click(function () {
```

Due to rules of event bubbling, the table is triggered too and we pass the second parameter to let JQuery now that we are only interested in events that are triggered by descendants that have 'remove_row' class.

I did quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqbh673q/) to check out what I mean and where I have removed extra bits of code and removed bad practises.

I did it quickly so if you find still problems,

Answer (score 0):

Try This its working

```
 <script>
var rowCount = 1;
function deletes(e){
    $('#rowCount' + e).remove();
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".add_more_rows").click(function () {
        //alert("121212");
        rowCount++;

        var recRow = '<p id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td>\n\
                    <td><input name="" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td>\n\
                    <td><input name="" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td>\n\
                    <td> <span id="remove_row'+rowCount+'" class="remove_row'+rowCount+'" style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="deletes('+rowCount+');">Delete Entry</span> </td></tr> </p>';

    $('#addedRows').append(recRow);

    });

});
```